# Specflow - best practice to test a list of servers that change per environment

Tags: c#, bdd, xunit, specflow

I'm a bit new to Specflow and BDD's Given/When/Then format and I'm having trouble doing something that I could normally achieve with a simple foreach.

My scenario is that I need to hit a list of servers given a particular environment as each environment has a different set of server names and can also have more or less servers depending on the environment. My first thought was to create example scenarios where I list out the servers in the example data, but that's hard coding the values I need to pass in and I can't do that.

What I'd ideally like to do is:

```
Given a list of servers {where the list of servers is stored in a local or global variable}
When I Ping the server
Then I receive status OK
```

I'd like to handle this *as if* the servers were listed in an example table where each server gets its own test. Is it possible to generate a table from a global or local variable? And if no, what's best practice for handling these kinds of scenarios? Do I just store the responses in a list/dictionary and validate the list in the `Then`?

Comment: How about loading test data from an excel file? I know you can do that in SpecFlow. Look into the [SpecFlow external data plugin](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Guides/externaldata.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, still not sure what best practice is, but I ended up getting the list of servers from the environment and storing them in a global list [Given a list of servers].
When getting the response, I stored them in a global dictionary where the key is server and the value is the http response [when I ping the servers]
and I validate the dictionary with fluent assertions [then all servers receive status ok]

I really feel like there should be a better way here though. I want this to be seen as the number of servers = the number of tests and not just ONE test.